# Selenium WebDriver Login to MondoZoo

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fill the logIn form of http://www.mondozoo.com, but when I try to locate the user name or the password I get this exception: `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`.

I tried with:

```
private static void enterMondoZoo(ChromeDriver driver){
    lg.info("Entering in mondoZoo:");
    driver.get("http://www.mondozoo.com");
    driver.findElement(By.className("mbarlog")).click();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000); //not the best wait in the world
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver.findElementByName("login").sendKeys("random");

    lg.info("Leaving the enteringMondoZoo");
}
```

I've tried with: `xpath- //*[@id="loginform"]/div[3]/form/div[1]/p[2]/input`
but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login model displayed is actually inside an iframe. So first you have to switch to the frame and try to enter values.

```
private static void enterMondoZoo(ChromeDriver driver){
    lg.info("Entering in mondoZoo:");
    driver.get("http://www.mondozoo.com");
    driver.findElement(By.className("mbarlog")).click();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000); //not the best wait in the world
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver.switchTo().frame("framebarrelogin");
    //Do all your login actions here
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='loginform']/div[3]/form/div[1]/p[2]/input")).sendKeys("random");
    //Login actions completed
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    lg.info("Leaving the enteringMondoZoo");
}
```

I used iframe ID attribute to switch to the frame. You can also use index instead of ID. Once you are done with all operations inside iframe, switch back to main page with "driver.switchTo().defaultContent()".

For more details about handling iframes, you can visit [this blog](http://allselenium.info/handling-iframes-using-selenium-webdriver/).